# Calculate difference between two values in a union

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, union

I've got the query below which is telling me people starting and finishing in a given time period.

```
select UserId,
cast(sum(CommissionPerc)/100 as numeric(2,1)) as PlacementCount,
datename(mm,startdate) + ' ' + 'Start' as DataType
from PlacementConsultants 
group by userid, datename(mm,StartDate)
union
select UserId,
cast(sum(CommissionPerc)/100 as numeric(2,1)) as PlacementCount,
datename(mm,EndDate) + ' ' + 'End' as DataType
from Placements 
group by userid, datename(mm,EndDate)
order by datatype
```

which outputs as follows:

```
791     4.0     May End
791     3.0     May Start
791     6.0     June End
791     2.0     June Start
791     1.0     July Start
```

But I would also like to have a column which writes as **MonthName Change**

e.g.

```
791    4.0    May End
791    3.0    May Start
791    -1.0   May Change
```

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Any particular reason why you need these as rows rather than columns?
This would be very easy if you had output with the following column headers, `UserID, Month, Start Value, End Value, Change`.

Comment: @Declan_K I'm using this later on as a pivot table so need the data as flat as possible.  The end result is column headers with the 3rd column as the output (e.g. in this case with May 3 columns called May End, May Start and May Change)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed your query into [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
;with CTE1 as (
    select
        UserId,
        cast(sum(CommissionPerc)/100 as numeric(2,1)) as PlacementCount,
        datename(mm,startdate) as Mon
    from PlacementConsultants 
    group by userid, datename(mm, StartDate)
), CTE2 as (
    select
        UserId,
        cast(sum(CommissionPerc)/100 as numeric(2,1)) as PlacementCount,
        datename(mm,EndDate) as Mon
    from Placements 
    group by userid, datename(mm, EndDate)
)
select C.UserId, C.PlacementCount, C.Mon + ' Start' as DataType
from CTE1 as C

union all

select C.UserId, C.PlacementCount, C.Mon + ' End' as DataType
from CTE2 as C

union all

select C1.UserId, C2.PlacementCount - C1.PlacementCount, C1.Mon + ' Change' as DataType
from CTE1 as C1
    inner join CTE2 as C2 on C2.UserId = C1.UserId and C2.Mon = C1.Mon
order by DataType
```

I've also changed [union to union all](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) since union will try to eliminate duplicate rows which you don't have

Comment: In that final Union All, c.Mon can't be bound.  What should it be bound to?

Comment: Cracking - that works an absolute treat! I need to have a proper look at CTE

Comment: take a look at @t-clausen.dk answer

Comment: @t-clausen.dk your solution is great, I've changed mine just because yours is not formatted. At the beginning I've also wanted to make as little changes to OP query as possible -> CTE around this query

Comment: Is it possible to put this whole thing in a table function?

Comment: it's possible to make a view, is it ok for you? just remove `;` and write `create view <Name of your view> as <query>`

Answer (score 1):

```
;with a as
(
select UserId,
cast(sum(CommissionPerc)/100 as numeric(2,1)) as PlacementCount,
datename(mm,startdate) as DataType
from PlacementConsultants 
group by userid, datename(mm,StartDate)
), b as
(
select UserId,
cast(sum(CommissionPerc)/100 as numeric(2,1)) as PlacementCount,
datename(mm,EndDate) as DataType
from Placements 
group by userid, datename(mm,EndDate)
)
select UserId, PlacementCount, DataType + ' Start' DataType
from a
union all
select UserId, PlacementCount, DataType + ' End' DataType
from b
union all
select a.UserId, b.PlacementCount- a.PlacementCount, a.DataType + ' Change' DataType
from a
join b
on a.userid = b.userid and a.DataType = b.DataType
```

Comment: I'm getting an ambiguous column name for the DataType + ' Change' section?